# Replace $X$ with $\mbox{diag}(x)$ in trace matrix derivative identity

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, trace, scalar-fields

There is a scaler-by-matrix derivative identity:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial X}trace\left(AXBX'C\right)=B'X'A'C'+BX'CA$$

How does this change if instead I am trying to find

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}trace\left(Adiag(x)Bdiag(x)'C\right)$$

where $x$ is a vector rather than a matrix.

My thinking is that all I have to do is multiply the original identity by a vector of ones as that would be the derivative of $diag(x)$. However, I'm not sure how the chain rule interacts with traces.

I ask as I am trying to calculate.
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial w}trace\left(Ddiag(w)\Omega diag(w)D'\right)$$

where $w \mathbb{\in R^{N}}$, $D\mathbb{\in R^{M\times N}}$, and $\Omega\mathbb{\in R^{N\times N}}$. Also $\Omega$ can be assumed to be positive definite.

This implies the result would be

$$\left(2\Omega diag(w)D'D\right)e$$

where $e \mathbb{\in R^{N}}$ is a vector of ones.

Comment: Don't multiply the matrix by $e$, but create a vector from its diagonal elements  $${\rm diag}\Big(2\Omega\,\,{\rm Diag}(w)\,D'D\Big)$$

Comment: @greg I appreciate this. Last night I had manually calculated the derivative when $w$ was length 5. When I got around to putting it in the computer today, I was able to verify that it was equivalent to your result. I would be happy to accept yours as the answer if you put it as one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ be defined by

$$f (\mathrm x) := \mbox{tr} \left( \mathrm A \, \mbox{diag} (\mathrm x) \, \mathrm B \, \mbox{diag} (\mathrm x) \, \mathrm C \right)$$

where $\mathrm A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$, $\mathrm B \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ and $\mathrm C \in \mathbb R^{n \times m}$ are given. The **directional derivative** of $f$ in the direction of $\mathrm v \in \mathbb R^n$ at $\mathrm x \in \mathbb R^n$ is given by

$$\begin{array}{rl} \displaystyle\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f (\mathrm x + h \,\mathrm v) - f (\mathrm x)}{h} &= \mbox{tr} \left( \mathrm A \, \mbox{diag} (\mathrm v) \, \mathrm B \, \mbox{diag} (\mathrm x) \, \mathrm C \right) + \mbox{tr} \left( \mathrm A \, \mbox{diag} (\mathrm x) \, \mathrm B \, \mbox{diag} (\mathrm v) \, \mathrm C \right)\\ &= \mbox{tr} \left( \mbox{diag} (\mathrm v) \, \mathrm B \, \mbox{diag} (\mathrm x) \, \mathrm C \, \mathrm A \right) + \mbox{tr} \left( \mbox{diag} (\mathrm v) \, \mathrm C \, \mathrm A \, \mbox{diag} (\mathrm x) \, \mathrm B \right)\\ &= \mathrm v^\top \mbox{diag}^{-1} \left( \mathrm B \, \mbox{diag} (\mathrm x) \, \mathrm C \, \mathrm A \right) + \mathrm v^\top \mbox{diag}^{-1} \left( \mathrm C \, \mathrm A \, \mbox{diag} (\mathrm x) \, \mathrm B \right)\end{array}$$

where $\mbox{diag}^{-1} : \mathbb R^{n \times n} \to \mathbb R^n$ is a linear function that takes a square matrix and extracts its main diagonal as a column vector. Thus, the **gradient** of $f$ is

$$\nabla_{\mathrm x} f(\mathrm x) = \color{blue}{\mbox{diag}^{-1} \left( \mathrm B \, \mbox{diag} (\mathrm x) \, \mathrm C \, \mathrm A \right) + \mbox{diag}^{-1} \left( \mathrm C \, \mathrm A \, \mbox{diag} (\mathrm x) \, \mathrm B \right)}$$

Comment: BTW, I really like the notation for inverse diagonal that you used.

Comment: I didn't invent it. Take a look at page 10 of [this](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~pift6266/A06/refs/minka-matrix.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

$\def\v{{\rm vec}}\def\d{{\rm diag}}\def\D{{\rm Diag}}\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$For
typing convenience, use a colon as a product
notation for the trace, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B = {\rm Tr}(AB^T) \;=\; \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij} B_{ij} \\
}$$
and assign a name to the function of interest
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= {\rm Tr}\left(AXBX^TC\right) \\
 &= CAXB:X \\&= A^TC^TXB^T:X \\
}$$
Then the gradient that you discovered can be written
as the differential relationship
$$\eqalign{
d\phi &= \big(CAXB + A^TC^TXB^T\big):dX \\
}$$
Let's also carefully name the diagonal operations. The `diag()` function creates a vector from the diagonal of its matrix argument, while the `Diag()` function does the opposite -
creating a diagonal matrix from a vector argument, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
X = \D(x) \quad\implies\quad x = \d(X) \\
}$$
The colon product has a very interesting property with respect to these
operators
$$\eqalign{
A:\D(x) &= \d(A):x \\
}$$
Using all of the above, we can calculate the gradient of interest as follows
$$\eqalign{
d\phi &= \big(CAXB + A^TC^TXB^T\big):\D(dx) \\
 &= \d\big(CAXB + A^TC^TXB^T\big):dx \\
\p{\phi}{x} ​&= \d\big(CAXB + A^TC^TXB^T\big) \\
}$$
Substituting $A=D,\,C=D^T\,$ and $B=\Omega=\Omega^T,\,$ the gradient can be simplified to
$$\eqalign{
\p{\phi}{x}
 ​&= \d\big(D^TDX\Omega + D^TDX\Omega\big) \\
 ​&= \d\big(2\,D^TDX\Omega\big) \\
}$$
Since $\d(M^T)=\d(M)\:$ even when $M^T\ne M$, this gradient can also be written as
$$\eqalign{
\p{\phi}{x}
 ​&= \d\big(2\,\Omega XD^TD\big) \qquad\qquad \\
}$$